Azure Automation, doing a GET from Invoke-WebRequest using Powershell 7.2 returns a bad request 400 error
Odd problem in Azure Automation, this code block doing a GET will work in 5.1, but not 7.2.  However, if I do a POST or UPDATE, in 7.2 it works fine.   I've done some research and I can't find any articles or posts suggesting anyone else is having an issue doing a GET.   I have the same problem using invoke-restmethod.  I have tested with and without the UseBasicParsing parameter. I could switch to 5.1, but I have a module written for 7 for interacting with this site and I would prefer to be able to be able to stick with using 7.2
I reduced it to the simplest possible request for this example:
$Params = @{
    Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    "x-4me-account" = "XXXXXXXX"
    }
    URI = 'https://api.4me.qa/v1/requests'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @Params


I think you should use Invoke-webrequest cmdlet.

I've tried both invoke-webrequest and invoke-restmethod same result both ways.

Can you provide more details ?

In 7.2 below PowerShell script worked fine for me using get method:
Without headers:
$rith = 'https://jsoner.typode.com/posts/1'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $rith -Method 'GET'

With @Params:
$rith = @{
    URI     = 'https://laceholder.typode.com/posts/1'
    Method  = 'GET'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @rith

With Headers:
$RithHead = @{
    "Authorization" = "My Token"
    "Custom-Header" = "Rith Value"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}
$rith = @{
    URI     = 'https://laceholder.typode.com/posts/1'
    Method  = 'GET'
    Headers = $RithHead
}
Invoke-RestMethod @rith


This also worked for me:
$test = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
$rithea = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer hhdu eeeoin"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}
$rithout = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $test -Method Get -Headers $rithea
$rithout 

